# Android Studio build.gradle file error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, build.gradle

I'm using a compatibility library for material card view and the dependency line is giving me error saying that : **This support library should not use a different version (21) than the compileSdkVersion(22)**. The support library is **com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are compiling with the SDK version 22 but the CardView dependency specifies SDK version 21.

You have two options:
1. Change CompileSdkVersion in build.gradle to 21
2. Change library version to `com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0`

Comment: I think you're right but just changing the dependency file version to 22 won't do it z I think I'll have to download the whole new dependency file which would then automatically update the build.gradle file.